# reached end of file while parsing but there is no missing brace

Tags: java, compiler-errors

So when i compile this program java gives an error message :reached end of file while parsing 
public class MohoscopeEngine implements HoroscopeEngine{
                                                        ^

```
//MohoscopeEngine.java


public class MohoscopeEngine implements HoroscopeEngine{

final String[] constant ={"Bring your friends from ", "and ", "to go to party at "};

String[] fiveplaces = {"Rocky", "Safford", "Chapin", "Art Museum", "Mead"};





/** generate random index for array without repeating*/
public String randomIndex(){
    int index = (int)(Math.floor(Math.random()*5));
    return fiveplaces[index];
}





public String getHoroscope(){

    //for(int i =0; i < index.length; i++)
    String mohoscope = constant[0] + randomIndex() + constant[1] + randomIndex() + constant[2] + randomIndex();
    return mohoscope;
}
}
```

i don't think i didn't enclose the class and i checked every bracket and brace and found nothing wrong. Why did the problem occur and how should i fix it?

Comment: Are you sure you have copied and pasted this accurately?  Because I copied and pasted your code into Eclipse, and I don't get your compile error.

Comment: Copy and paste your question back to IDE your problem should get solved

Comment: do you also have package and import statements?

Comment: Yeah actually this is exactly what i wrote on jEdit, my friends copied my code and ran smoothly, but i kept getting the complier error. It's really freaking me out.